# Vue 3 with Laravel Blade template doesn't work on production build

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to use Vue 3 SFC with template inside regular Laravel Blade file like this:

**Test.vue**

```
<script setup>

import { ref} from 'vue';

const testValue = ref('Works');

</script>
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<head>
    @stack('js')
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**test.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@push('js')
    @vite(['resources/js/test.js'])
@endpush
@section('content')
    <span>@{{ testValue }}</span>
@endsection
```

**test.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Test from "./components/Test.vue";
const app = createApp(Test).mount("#app");
```

I know it's complicated and I should write template inside SFC, but I prefer using blade files and it works fine after running **npm run dev**:

[image]

However, after running **npm run build** I see a blank page without template from blade file.

[image]

Does anyone know what's the reason for this and how to make it work? Here's my config:

**vite.js.config**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
        server: {
            hmr: true,
            https: false,
            host: 'localhost',
            proxy: {
                // Proxying websockets or socket.io
                '/app': {
                    target: 'wss://localhost:6001',
                    ws: true
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            laravel(
                {
                    input: [
                        'resources/js/test.js',
                    ],
                    refresh: true,
                }),
            vue({
                template: {
                    transformAssetUrls: {
                        base: null,
                        includeAbsolute: false,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
            },
        },
        build: {
            chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1000,
        },
        define: {
            __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: true,
            __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: true,
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move  @stack('js') in your app.blade.php inside the body tag. Just before you close the body.